# Could this nothch in my sash been made by termites?

Tags: wood, termite

[image]Could a termite or something else have made this hole? My wife is pretty sure it didn't exist before.

Comment: Do you have the right pic? this looks like a sash with a big gouge in the edge....

Comment: Also, the gouge looks to be painted, meaning it's been there at least as long as that paint has.

Comment: yes that's the right pic. that gouge is what i am wondering about

Comment: thanks eric, yeah that is an excellent point and did occur to me as well but I am home maintenance noob and wasn't sure whether there is any chance the wood is naturally that colour

Comment: Is there any matching damage on the jamb side of the window?

Comment: Someday, you're not going to be a noob anymore and you're going to look back on this post and laugh at yourself for not knowing this right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not termites, it is not carpenter bees. It has been there for some time since it has paint in the gouge. It looks like somebody cut on it while it was open, but can't tell for sure, the picture gets too fuzzy when it gets enlarged enough to show small details. Nevertheless, it has been there for sometime.

Comment: My guess: It's a notch cut by a nesting homo-sapiens for a cable to an outside weather sensor / security camera / unidentified gizmo.

Comment: thanks Jack and others who answered same. I think the paint is pretty irrefutable evidence that it's been there since before we moved in

Comment: Looks like kludgery.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a little big for termites. My guess would be a carpenter bee.

[image: Carpenter Bee Hole]

Comment: eep. if so what can i do about it?

Comment: Who downvoted this with no comment? :(